# Proving Reversal of a Language in Recursive Way

Tags: induction, formal-languages, recursion, regular-language, regular-expressions

We define the $reverse$ of a string as follows:

$(x_1x_2...x_n)^R=x_nx_{n-1}...x_1$

where $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in \Sigma$. We can also define the reverse of a language by

$L^R= \lbrace s' |  \exists s \in L : s' = s^R \rbrace$.

Prove that if $L$ is a regular language, $L^R$ is as well.

$Hint:$ Define the $reverse$ operation for regular expressions, recursively.

Although I have the hint I can't find the answer. Can you help me?

Comment: If you know that regular languages are given by a finite state automaton (i.e. a directed graph with labels), you could also try to think about how this automaton would give you an automaton for the reverse language (which then has to be regular again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Try to solve the following questions
$$
  (K \cup L)^R = {?} \qquad (KL)^R = {?} \qquad  (L^*)^R = {?}
$$